# Need to read numbers fromm file and store even numbers in an array and print it|| python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f = open("LFx.txt", "r")
numbers=f.read(10)
array=[]
print(numbers)
for num in numbers:
    if num%2==0:
       array.append(num)
print(array)
```

I am getting type error everytime when i run this i dont now whats the problem is.Please Help me with this question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the *full text* of the error or traceback.

Comment: Can you share content of file

Answer (score 1):

numbers is a string, you need to transform the string into numbers.

suppose that you have the following data :

```
data = "1, 2, 1, 4"
```

then you can retrieve the numbers using

```
numbers = [int(value) for value in data.split(,)]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read from file it is in string format.

you need to type cast your data first and then do the operations.

you can try something like this:

```
f = open("LFx.txt", "r")
numbers=f.read(10)
array=[]
# here convert each number in string format to int
numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers.split() if i.isdigit()]
for num in numbers:
    if num%2==0:
       array.append(num)
print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more information? How are the numbers stored in the file? line by line? all in one line? Seperated by commas? seperated by new line characters?

Reading the file will give you the stored information as a string, you can not execute mathematical operations between strings and integers.

this is invalid:

```
f = "1,2,3,4,5" #numbers read from your file
array = []
for num in f:
    if num%2==0:
        array.append(num)

print(array)
```

But this prints [2,4]:

```
f = 1,2,3,4,5
array = []
for num in f:
    if num%2==0:
        array.append(num)
print(array)
```

one solution would be:

```
import os

a = []

o = open("filename.txt","r")
y = o.read()
z = 0

for c in y.split():
    a.append(int(c))

#now you can do mathematical operations on the elements in a

array = []

for num in a:
    if num%2==0:
        array.append(num)

print(array)
```

Comment: They are just line by line!

Comment: i hope now you get it